# LS_COLORS from Raspbian to Debian

Tags: raspbian, ssh, debian

this is more a question about fashion than functionality.
I really like the way the bash is colored by default in Raspbian, I find it very helpful and pleasant to the eyes. That being said, I also run a Debian machine and I would really like to have its bash to be colorized just like the Raspbian one. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ExploWare did a good job of explaining `ls`.  For more about the command prompt see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/how-to-customize-bashrc-to-configure-command-prompt) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/how-to-customize-bashrc-to-configure-command-prompt).  The prompt colors are done with *ANSI escape sequences* compatible with any terminal on linux (e.g., try `echo -e "\033[32mcheese\033[0m"` and don't forget the `-e`).  There's a generic guide to those in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

Comment: Whoops! Those two "here"s are the same link.  This is the other one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the lines starting with `PS1` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and/or `/home/pi/.bashrc`
Those lines set the (color)layout for the prompt, the line where you can type at.

for the colors in a filelisting by executing `ls` the option `--color=auto` is useful.
this may also be defined as an alias; try executing this:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
ls ~  
ls -la ~
```

Do you like these colors to be permanent on your Debian (or any other color-enabled terminal, like shipped with Ubuntu, Suse, Arch, etc.) then copy the `PS1` lines and the `alias` line to the `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` at a linuxcomputer of your choice :)

BTW: googling for "PS1 bash" will show you even more ways to make a pretty prompt, like adding a timestamp